# Spark does not distribute work

Tags: apache-spark

I set up two virtual machines to test Spark in a distributed setup. It seems that my jobs are only run locally on one node, the one I use to submit the job.

One node is run as datanode/worker node and the second one is additionally namenode/secondary-namenode 
I configured the underlying hadoop to use Yarn.
The `jps` command confirms that the various services are started correctly and basically available after I expected the start*-scripts in hadoop/spark.

I use htop to "track" if the other node is used, but the cpu usage jumps between 2 an 3% --> probably not used. I wonder what I am missing here.

I start my job with this command:
./spark-submit --class com.... DistributedTest --master yarn-client myJar.jar

This is the class I am executing (the data.txt file is about 1GB pure text)

```
  public class DistributedTest
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
            throws IOException
        {

            SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application");
            JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
            JavaRDD<String> logData = sc.textFile("hdfs://woodpecker:10001/husr/data.txt");// .persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY());

            long numAs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>()
            {
                public Boolean call(String s)
                {
                    return s.contains("a");
                }
            }).count();

            long numBs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>()
            {
                public Boolean call(String s)
                {
                    return s.contains("b");
                }
            }).count();

            sc.close();

            String s = "Lines with a: " + numAs + ", lines with b: " + numBs;
            System.out.println(s);


        }
    }
```

Anyone any ideas why my setup does not distribute

Comment: you are sure that both your machines are on the same spark cluster?

Comment: How do I confirm this? I assumed both nodes know each other because starting the start-all script also starts the node and all its services ? How could they not be on the same cluster?

Comment: do you see both workers on the same gui?

Comment: Ah ok, no I don't. I only see only the worker on my master node. How do I let the worker join the cluster?

Comment: It will not actually be distributed considering just two machines. One of them has to be the master and the other is the slave. You'll need to have 3 machine set to form a cluster. The slave is the one who is going to do all the job while the master will just perform load balancing which in your case does not exist...

Comment: You're calling the `logData.filter` twice. I think will be better if you cache it after load.

Answer (score 0):

The `filter` operation is definitely distributed, and `count` is partially computed on a worker, while the total count is calculated back on the master. The result of the count is also on the master.

Filtering one GB of data isn't really going to stress Spark anyway, so you should only see a short CPU spike on the worker. Rather take a look at I/O usage.

Your app is fine, there must be something wrong with your setup.

Comment: Well only partly of course, the length of the RDD is distributed, but it then sums all the sub-length on the master.

Comment: do you have a suggestion how to use more cpu time on the nodes? My master is at 100% while the second node is ideling-around. I still doubt that is right. I would expect to see at least a bit more cpu usage on my nodes.

Answer (score 0):

First, you go through your Spark UI and make sure you have multiple workers and it is also depend on how much partition you have in your Rdd.